# How to map aggregation to a single table with linq2db

Tags: mysql, linq2db

I would like to map an object, containing an aggregated instance of another object, to a single table.

I have two POCOs like:

```
[Table(Name = "TheTable")]

class A 
{
  [Column(Name = "PropA"), NotNull] 
  public string PropA { get; set; }

  public B TheOtherObject { get; set; }
}

class B
{
  public string PropB { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to map this, without repeating all the properties of class B in class A just for the purpose of mapping.

```
| ID | PropA | PropB |
```

Is there any way to achieve this with linq2db?

I'm using an MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution...

Annotating class A with

```
[Column("PropB", "TheOtherObject.PropB")]
```

gives the desired behaviour.